# Calling web service for the notification action for a remote push notification on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, remote-notifications

I need to call 2 web service calls when user clicks on a button on the interactive notification. This notification is a remote push notification. The web service calls work fine when the application is in foreground or background. But the behavior is not consistent when the app is in suspended state (user forcefully killed the app). Some times it works well i.e, calls both the web service calls. some times it fails and the most common reason I have seen in the logs is

> Application background launch action for notification response action
>   vscd.escalate received action response  {
>       description = "The operation couldn’t be completed. (BSActionErrorDomain error 4.)"; }>

I have only "**Remote notifications**" enabled under capabilities. "**Background fetch**" is not enabled.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I figured out that I was calling the completionHandler before even executing the web service requests and thats the reason the service calls fail.

Answer (score 1):

I had this happen when I hadn't registered the notification delegate properly on app launch - just like they warn in the documentation. The fix was to ensure the delegate was set explicitly during `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

Previously, my app set the delegate during load of the initial view controller, which works for every case except when the app is not running in the foreground or the background, but is launched by the notification itself.